# How to link Button to another page in react JS?

Tags: html, reactjs

Hi guys so I'm trying to use button in my react-bootstrap app and what that button do is everytime user click the button it will redirect the user to another page of the web-app. But for some reason it didn't work, can anyone help me please ? my router already work for other components such as header, footer, etc. But it didn't work for the Button.

Here's my code:

```
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="Aboutus">
                    <Col sm={12} lg={6}>
                        <h1>About Us</h1>
                        <hr style={{border:'2px solid', color:'#10255A', width:'25.7%'}}></hr>
                        <p>The hotel itself possess a trendy design with attention to comfort, 
                           quality and value based accommodation.
                        </p>
                        <button as={Link} to={"/Room"}>See Room</button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={12} lg={6}>
                        <img src="#"></img>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use bootstrap `<Button>` instead of native HTML `<button>` for that and change `href` instead of `to`:

```
<Button as={Link} href={"/Room"}>
  See Room
</Button>;
```

Live Example:

[image: Edit React bootstrap demo (forked)]

*You will need to open sandbox URL in another tab to see url change*

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. If I use this method can I change the style of my button to my preference ? how can I do it in my css ?

Comment: You surely can, you can use className or styles object to the Button itself to style your button just like a native HTML button

Comment: I updated some styles for the button inside the codesanbox, you can check it there for better understanding. I used both className and styles object.

Comment: Hi, I tried it already but it didn't work, when I try to inspect the element the button contains the "btn btn-primary" even though I didn't write it on my class. How can I remove it ?

Comment: It's a predefined class when you use the Button component from bootstrap. If you don't want to use it, then pick a few other classes from [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using normal `button`, not `Button` in `react-bootstrap`.

Just update it

```
<Button as={Link} to={"/Room"}>See Room</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option and just to take advantage of the native link component without using the Button component, is to use the bootstrap classes(which support styling a tags as a button):

```
<Link to="/Room" className="btn btn-primary">
 See Room
</Link>
```